# "No registered Auth Providers found matching any provider" using client and ApiKeyAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack

I have configured my serviceStack host with autentication via ApiKey.

Using the browser it function but, using the client it give me this exception:

"No registered Auth Providers found matching any provider"

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                () => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings), new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                }
            ));
```

and this is the client:

```
var client = CreateClient();
            client.BearerToken="Z77sPzzPaPYVyeZE8hBy0Jr83xyvly5f";

            var response = client.Get(new VISOrdiniVisureRequest {  });

            Assert.That(response.OrdiniVisure.TotalCount, Is.GreaterThan(1));
```

Comment: Weird, the [error message indicates you haven't got any AuthProviders registered](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/73139cb66554fb8a3855999c3fe1da7d9202dd20/src/ServiceStack/AuthenticateAttribute.cs#L65) suggesting a possible misconfiguration, how many auth providers does `AuthenticateService.GetAuthProviders(null)` return within your Service impl?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing that wat the test project that give mi this error.
I understand that I have to configure also here the host environment.